# Efficient calculation on complete columns (pytables, hdf5, numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, pytables

I have a simple HDF5 file (created by PyTables) with ten columns and 100000 rows. For every value I have to apply a simple linear equation, with different parameters per column and write the stuff to CSV.

My naive approach was to loop over the table:

```
for row in table.iterrows():
    print "%f,%f,..." % (row['a'] * 1.0 + 2.0, row['b'] * 3.0 + 4.0, ...)
```

But I wonder, whether it would be more efficient to select the columns and calculate them that way and later iterate over the resulting arrays:

```
a = numpy.add(numpy.multiply(table.cols.a, 1.0), 2.0)
b = numpy.add(numpy.multiply(table.cols.b, 3.0), 4.0)
```

But this is even slower, it seems.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your performance is likely going to be limited by the writing to CSV, but other than that, this problem is exactly what [numexpr](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/expr_class.html#) was made for.

You could use the Expr.set_output method to write your result back to hdf5 instead of iterating over the result and writing to CSV directly, and then look for a more efficient method of converting this result column to CSV in a single optimized call; or find a way to do away with the CSV in the first place, because it does not make much sense to use it if performance is indeed a major concern.

Comment: Many thanks, as a PyTables newbie I never heard of this feature before. In a quick check, this is about one third faster (~400ms) than using iterrows (~600ms)! Cool! (The numpy approach is so slow, that I interrupted it after some minutes.)